# How to set Mime type in jsPlumb save function

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

I'm trying to save a flowchart diagram in jsPlumb (I'm using jsPlumb toolkit edition). My save function look like below:

```
 jsPlumb.on(controls, "tap", function () {
        toolkit.save({
            url: "http://localhost:51987/api/Index/Save",
        });
    });
```

My question is I don't know how to set the **request header to application/json** in jsPlumb save function.

I'm getting "Failed to load resource in the browser console: the server responded with a status of 415 (Unsupported Media Type)" error.

Checking the request in the Fiddler:

> HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type Cache-Control: no-cache Pragma:
>   no-cache Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Expires: -1
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-SourceFiles:
>   =?UTF-8?B?QzpccHJvamVjdHNcc3Bpa2VzXHBsdW1wLXNwaWtlXGpzUGx1bWJBUElcanNQbHVtYkFQSVxhcGlcSW5kZXhcU2F2ZQ==?=
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Mon, 21 Nov 2016 16:33:54 GMT
>   Content-Length: 910
>
> {"Message":"The request entity's media type 'text/plain' is not
>   supported for this resource.","ExceptionMessage":"No
>   MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type
>   'JsPlumbViewModel' from content with media type
>   'text/plain'.","ExceptionType":"System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException","StackTrace":"
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent
>   content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger
>   formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync(HttpContent content,
>   Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger
>   formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the headers when creating the JSPlumb instance:

```
var toolkit = jsPlumbToolkit.newInstance({
  saveUrl:"http://sava-data.com",
  saveHeaders:{
    "Content-Type":"application/json"
  }
});
```